# Skyrim Dragonborn DLC: black book glitches

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Can somebody help me? I know it's an old game, but I have opened the black books after collecting them all, in order to change my skills. Now I'm back in Skyrim and I keep taking damage, as if I'm in the dark area in the book. I can't revert to another save as it's all autosaves of when the glitch happened.

I don't want to lose my character so any help is appreciated!